# Can not deserialize json data in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter development, I was trying to get data from REST API and its response was like this

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
       "pagination": {
           "pages": 2,
           "pageSize": 10,
           "items": 20,
           "currentPage": 1
       },
      "items": [
        {
            "_id": "5f9524594361c1001f249f5b",
            "firstName": "sudesh",
            "lastName": "maduranga",
            "role": "admin",
            "email": "ddd@mailinator.com",
            "activated": true,
            "disabled": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f9524594361c1001f249f5c",
            "firstName": "Sam",
            "lastName": "Anderson",
            "role": "admin",
            "email": "sss@mailinator.com",
            "activated": true,
            "disabled": 0
        }
     ]
   }
 }
```

In flutter I have this model class to use that response

```js
class UserListResponseModel {
  final bool success;
  final Data data;

  UserListResponseModel( {
    this.success,
    this.data,
  });

  factory UserListResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return UserListResponseModel(
      success: parsedJson['success'],
      data: Data.fromJson(parsedJson['data']),
    );
  }
}

class Data {
  final PaginationModel pagination;
  final List<Users> items;

  Data( {
    this.pagination,
    this.items,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    var usersList = parsedJson['data'] as List;

    List<Users> userList = usersList.map((i) => Users.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return Data(
        pagination: PaginationModel.fromJson(parsedJson['pagination']),
        items: userList
    );
  }
}

class Users {
  String userId;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String role;
  String email;
  String activated;
  String disabled;

  Users({
    this.userId,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.role,
    this.email,
    this.activated,
    this.disabled
  });

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return Users(
      userId: parsedJson['userId'],
      firstName: parsedJson['firstName'],
      lastName: parsedJson['lastName'],
      role: parsedJson['role'],
      email: parsedJson['email'],
      activated: parsedJson['disabled']
    );
  }
}
```

when I run the app it gives this error

```js
E/flutter (29178): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
E/flutter (29178): Receiver: null
E/flutter (29178): Tried calling: map<Users>(Closure: (dynamic) => Users)
E/flutter (29178): #0      UserService.getAllUsers (package:frontend/services/user/user_service.dart:51:7)
E/flutter (29178): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29178): #1      _UserListState.getUserList (package:frontend/screens/users/list.dart:30:52)
E/flutter (29178): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29178): #2      _UserListState.initState (package:frontend/screens/users/list.dart:22:5)
E/flutter (29178): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
E/flutter (29178): #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter (29178): #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (29178): #6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3324:20)
E/flutter (29178): #7      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
E/flutter (29178): #8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
E/flutter (29178): #9      StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4708:5)
E/flutter (29178): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
E/flutter (29178): #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
E/flutter (29178): #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
E/flutter (29178): #13     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4987:5)
```

I used this line of code as well,

```
var usersList = parsedJson['data']['items'] as List;
```

but no luck, the error is

```js
E/flutter (29178): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (29178): Receiver: null
E/flutter (29178): Tried calling: []("items")
E/flutter (29178): #0      UserService.getAllUsers (package:frontend/services/user/user_service.dart:51:7)
E/flutter (29178): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29178): #1      _UserListState.getUserList (package:frontend/screens/users/list.dart:30:52)
E/flutter (29178): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29178): #2      _UserListState.initState (package:frontend/screens/users/list.dart:22:5)
E/flutter (29178): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
```

I'm stuck on this, please help me. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check before mapping the list. If it is null then you can not map it. You must return null. Your model should look like this:

```
class UserListResponseModel {
  bool success;
  Data data;

  UserListResponseModel({this.success, this.data});

  UserListResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    success = json['success'];
    data = json['data'] != null ? new Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['success'] = this.success;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  Pagination pagination;
  List<Items> items;

  Data({this.pagination, this.items});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    pagination = json['pagination'] != null
        ? new Pagination.fromJson(json['pagination'])
        : null;
    if (json['items'] != null) {
      items = new List<Items>();
      json['items'].forEach((v) {
        items.add(new Items.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.pagination != null) {
      data['pagination'] = this.pagination.toJson();
    }
    if (this.items != null) {
      data['items'] = this.items.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Pagination {
  int pages;
  int pageSize;
  int items;
  int currentPage;

  Pagination({this.pages, this.pageSize, this.items, this.currentPage});

  Pagination.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    pages = json['pages'];
    pageSize = json['pageSize'];
    items = json['items'];
    currentPage = json['currentPage'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['pages'] = this.pages;
    data['pageSize'] = this.pageSize;
    data['items'] = this.items;
    data['currentPage'] = this.currentPage;
    return data;
  }
}

class Items {
  String sId;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String role;
  String email;
  bool activated;
  int disabled;

  Items(
      {this.sId,
      this.firstName,
      this.lastName,
      this.role,
      this.email,
      this.activated,
      this.disabled});

  Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    firstName = json['firstName'];
    lastName = json['lastName'];
    role = json['role'];
    email = json['email'];
    activated = json['activated'];
    disabled = json['disabled'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['firstName'] = this.firstName;
    data['lastName'] = this.lastName;
    data['role'] = this.role;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['activated'] = this.activated;
    data['disabled'] = this.disabled;
    return data;
  }
}
```

You can use this [website](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) to convert the JSON to a Dart model.